# How can I parse a list of nested XML objects in Java with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I've parsed objects like the following, without any issues:

```
<response>
    <myObject>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>abc</name>
    </myObject>

    <myObject>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>def</name>
    </myObject>
</response>
```

with a class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="myObject")
public class MyObject{

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    long id;

    @XmlElement(name="name")
    String name;

    /* getters and setters ... etc.. */

}
```

This works fine, with my API calls I get a list of `MyObjects` as expected. 
but how do I handle this type of response:

```
<response>
    <objectWrapper>
        <myObject>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>abc</name>
        </myObject>

        <myObject>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>def</name>
        </myObject>
    </objectWrapper>
</response>
```

At first I thought building an `ObjectWrapper` class would do the trick, like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="objectWrapper")
public class ObjectWrapper{

    @XmlElement(name="myObject")
    List<MyObject> myObject;
    /* getters and setters ... etc.. */

}
```

Then I thought about using `@XmlElementWrapper` too, but how? 
Can I just remove the `@XmlRootElement` from the class and ad `@XmlElementWrapper` on the list?

Edit:  No, I cannot remove the `@XmlRootElement`

Comment: Doesn't your solution with `ObjectWrapper` work ? There is no problem to have `@XmlRootElement` in both `ObjectWrapper` and `MyObject` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your class is named `ObjectWrapper` or not.
You need to specify correct wrapper name in `@XmlElementWrapper` which is `objectWrapper`.

Your `ObjectWrapper` class should look like :

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "response" )
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class ObjectWrapper
{
    @XmlElementWrapper( name = "objectWrapper" )
    @XmlElement( name = "myObject" )
    private List<MyObject> myObjects;


    public void setMyObjects( List<MyObject> objects )
    {
        this.myObjects  = objects;
    }

    public List<MyObject> getMyObjects()
    {
        return myObjects;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write it like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="response")
public class Response {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="objectWrapper")
    @XmlElement(name="myObject")
    List<MyObject> myObject;
    /* getters and setters ... etc.. */

}
```

You don't need an `ObjectWrapper` class.